# Launch a specific Activity when the app enters foreground from background

Tags: android, android-activity

In the app I am developing, some screens need to be password protected. So if the user leaves the app (by pressing home or another app comes in foreground or the screen turns off) and comes back after a period of time (30 sec), the app is supposed to ask for password (show password screen) before showing the screen he left at.

What I have tried so far are:

- In `Application` class I keep track of activity lifecycle using `ActivityLifecycleCallbacks`and trigger 2 events, one when the app goes in background and another when it comes back to foreground.
- In the 'background' event I track the current timestamp. And then in the 'foreground' event I check if the app was in background for 30 sec and if so then tell the current `Activity` to launch the password screen.

This works ok. But the problem is, this way the protected content/screen is visible for a while until the password screen is launched (as the password screen is launched by the content screen itself).

Is there a better way to do it so that the password screen comes first?

Comment: Why don't you start the password activity (with clear_top flag) from the Application class itself?

Comment: @Shaishav that's exactly what I was doing, but it doesn't solve that problem. And I delegated the launch to the content activity as it has the knowledge of whether it needs password protection or not.

Comment: Are you using `onActivityPaused()` and `onActivityResumed()` lifecycle methods in Application class to determine if the app goes to foreground/background?

Comment: @Shaishav using `start` & `stop` events.

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is a basic great use case for java Inheritance that can be easily solved by base class that inherited from the activity class.

First we create a base class:

```
public class NeedPasswordActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        //Check time stamp here
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        //Set time step here
    }
}
```

Then in each activity that need to be password verified we inherit from our `NeedPasswordActivity`:

```
public class NeedToHavePassowrdActivity extends NeedPasswordActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume(); //call the code from our NeedPasswordActivity and check time stamp before loading the activity
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause(); //call the code from our NeedPasswordActivity and set time stamp
    }
}
```

Important: `super.` must be the first line in the method so nothing from our activity will be called before timestamp is verified

Answer (score 0):

This might sound like a hack mainly because it is. You can make your application class determining background/foreground logic as following:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application implements ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {

    public boolean userLoggedOff;
    private Handler mHandler; 

    ... 

    @Override  
    public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {
        Log.i("Activity Resumed", activity.getLocalClassName());

        if (userLoggedoff) 
             startPasswordActivity() 
        else { 
             mHandler.cancelCallbacksAndMessages(null); 
             userLoggedOff = false;
        } 
    }  

    @Override  
    public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {
        Log.i("Activity Paused", activity.getLocalClassName());

        mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
             @Override 
             public void run() { 
                  userLoggedOff = true;
             } 
        }, 30000); 
    }  

    ... 

}
```

This will log the user off as soon as any activity is paused but none are resumed within 30 secs. Now, to tackle the case of sensitive info showing up instantaneously we can add a view which covers the entire screen to each sensitive activity layout to hide the screen until we determine user legitimacy. Then, in each such activity we can add:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    if (!((MyApplication) getApplicatio()).userLoggedOff))
         (findViewByID(R.id.opaqueView)).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

This just might work for your use case.

Comment: @Shaisab the logic for tracking app's foreground/background state is already there and working. Thanks for suggesting the view overlay, I was also thinking about blurring out the sensitive content if I could not solve the issue in question.

Comment: Ohh..that is why I asked what method you were using for that. However, there was a power cut in my home so i couldn't get your response before posting my answer which i did as soon as the power came back on. :)